# Name of a team of authors (husband and wife) who wrote young adult sci-fi/fantasy

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

They wrote several books but the books were not a series.

The one book that stands out in my mind was about 2 teen or pre-teen people on different planets that were able to communicate psychically with each other. Another book, a bit less unique about a young psychic boy being chased by an investigator. The only specific information I have is the book authors were a husband and wife writing team.

These books were written pre-1970.

Comment: If you're looking for a pre-1970 married couple who wrote SF together, the #1 guess will be [C.L. Moore](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?453) and [Henry Kuttner](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?452).  They used a bunch of pen names, sometimes together as with [Lewis Padgett](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?2390).

Comment: @DavidW Thank you. I will research the authors further as I do not see mention of young adult novels credited to them in my cursory review.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This sounds like possibly Jeff and Jean Sutton. They collaborated on a number of YA books including:  [Lord of the Stars](http://www.librarything.com/work/4472490) and [The Beyond](http://www.librarything.com/work/1413589).

The first book you are seeking I believe is the Lord of the Stars.

*"Danny grew up alone on an alien planet guided by the telepathic thoughts of unseen Zandro. Finally he makes mental contact with humans on another world and learns he is being used in a plot to conquer the universe."*

From what I remember the latter I believe is the 2nd book you are seeking.  A description at the site lists the following:

*"An agent, sent to a distant planet where those with telepathic powers are banished, and ordered to find the person with the ability to move objects by thought"*

Comment: They were the first husband/wife team that popped into my head as I read the original post. I remember, as a kid, checking out their books from a public library and enjoying them.

Comment: Lorendiac Oh my goodness. I believe these are the books! Thank you so much. I didn’t think I would ever be able to solve the mystery. I also read them as a kid from the library. If they stuck with us this long they were phenomenal story telling. Thank you again.

Comment: Glad to hear these were it. I agree.  I found them quite enjoyable to read all those years ago. I hope you enjoy re-reading them.